# Not all elements could be created (x264enc or TIVidEnc1 ? )

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to create `x264enc`:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
GstElement *pipeline, *src, *enc, *rtp, *sink;
...
...

src = gst_element_factory_make ("videotestsrc", "src");
enc = gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", "enc");
rtp = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264pay", "rtp");
sink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "sink");

pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

if (!pipeline || !src || !enc || !rtp || !sink  ) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }
}
```

If I erase the line:

```
enc = gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", "enc");
```

the program will run and if I run the command:

```
gst-inspect x264enc
```

I get information about the encoder, so it exists...

I also tried to change from `x264enc` to `TIVidEnc1` with no success.

Any ideas..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably don't have x264enc encoder installed on your system. This encoder is not included in the base packages of gstreamer and you need to download it manually and build it onto your system.
after downloading build it onto ugly lib of gstreamer .
I am not sure but in the updated ugly libraries of Gstreamer it may have been included as well.So updating your gstreamer may work as well.